# Timestamp in cell - different timestamps, but they have to stay in cell

Tags: excel

:)

I'm making a status report where they can choose between:

1. Planned (no timestamp)
2. In progress (one timestamp, there have to stay)
3. Done (one timestamp, there have to stay)

But I am using this function: `=IF(B84="In progress";IF(F84<>"";F84;NOW());"")`

In `in progress` and `Done`, the timestamps are coming but also dissapearing because of the `=In progress`

I don't know how to make sure that it appears when `in progress` but then stays even though the status is changed to `done`

[image]

Please assist, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your screenshot so we can see where you have written this formula and what's not working !

Comment: The `NOW()` function will recalculate and change every time the worksheet changes. You will need VBA to create a static timestamp.

Comment: =IF(B88<>"";IF(F88<>"";F88;NOW());"") this one is inserting a timestamp, and do not remove it again, but it wil also insert a date as soon there is a change in B88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem in VBA..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range: Set B = Range("B:B")
       Dim v As String
       If Intersect(Target, B) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       Application.EnableEvents = False
          v = Target.Value
          If v = "In progress" Then Target.Offset(0, 4) = Now()
          If v = "Done" Then Target.Offset(0, 5) = Now()
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```